# How to add a normal app to an existing extension in iOS?

Tags: ios, imessage, ios-extensions

I created an iMessage app extension with the predefined Xcode template. I now want to add a 'normal' app to that extension. How should I proceed? I just tried to add a storyboard and a new scheme but it fails with following error:

```
The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: NotFound ("Application "mybundleid" is unknown to FrontBoard").
```

Comment: You can just create new app then add that extension in your app project, if not works then just create new extension with similar bundle id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new target of type Single View Application to your project:

[image]

Then select all source files (.swift, .storyboard) you want to use within your new app and tick the new target in "Target Membership":

[image]

---

Update:

After further discussion in the comments, I understand you want to:

- The user installs an iMessage extension from the iMessage extention App Store within iMessages
- A depending app is installed (and shown to the user on home screen) automatically in the same installation process.

This is not possible. The App shown in the project is actually installed but is hidden/not visible to the user.

The only way to install App and extension at the same time is to install an actual app.

Comment: But if I understand correctly, that's a completely different app under the same project, right? What I want is that the standard app target goes with the iMessage extension so that the user does only one install.

Comment: By the way, if that can help, I installed the iMessage extension first with the template proposed in Xcode

Comment: Your question was "How to add a normal app...". (The Extension is installed with your app in one install btw.)

Comment: your quote misses the end of the question. I have created an imessage extension with the xcode predefined structure. That does create a target for the _non_ imessage stuff (as you can see with your print screen TEST target). What I want is be able to add code to TEST and _without_ creating TEST2.

Comment: Updated answer accordingly. To add code to your target, select the code file and tick "TEST" as Target Membership" as shown in screenshots.